# bitcoin core command line walletpassphrase incorrect but works for the main system?

Tags: bitcoin-core, passphrase, command-line-options

My command line won't accept my passphrase, but on the main system it says it's correct and I can change it. I want to dump private key but no matter what I try, it continues to say incorrect passphrase. What can I do?

Comment: Can you explain more precisely what works and what doesn't, e.g. specific commands and/or mouseclicks, and what exactly happens?  I don't know what you mean by "the main system".

Answer (score 4):

If your passphrase contains spaces or special characters, you will need to wrap it with single quotes (`'`) so that the debug console can properly parse your passphrase. For example, if your passphrase were `This is my passphrase`, then your command should be

```
walletpassphrase 'This is my passphrase'
```

Comment: Wow, this saved my day! Can't believe only *single quotes* (and not double quotes) works!